# How to generate source code from avro schema in maven(eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, schema, avro

```
I know this is not the first time this question has been asked. As i have gone through several links, but unable to understand why avro schema is not generating the source code when no error is being thrown in maven(eclipse).  I have tried deleting 'pluginManagement' from pom.xml file but it throws error.
```

Tried deleting .m2 repo,mvn clean, mvn install, nothing seems to work. Not sure what is the issue.

Also, could you please tell me how to add 'fieldVisibility=private' argument while generating the source code from the command line.
Please guide! Thank you!

This is the pom.xml file

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>ProducerConsumer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>ProducerConsumer</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>confluent</id>
        <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                            <fieldVisibility>PRIVATE</fieldVisibility>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.avro</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 17):

I would suggest to use the correct setup like this:

There are two things: you are using not the avro-maven-plugin and also you have configured it in the pluginManagement instead of in using correctly located in `<build><plugins>...</plugins></build>`.

```
<project..>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>schema</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
              <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Than you should accept the answer or at least upvote the answer.

Comment: I have less than 15 reputations to upvote the response!

Comment: Ensure your avro schema files have the expected extension `.avsc`.
In case of a typo error for example `.asvc` instead of `.avsc`, the plugin just ignore files without warning.