# Convert a POJO to AVRO schema

Tags: java, maven, avro, pojo

Given a POJO (e.g. User.java), are there any Maven plug-ins that convert it to an AVRO schema avsc on compilation?

I tried `Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(User.class)` but this approach doesn't generate avsc on compilation.

Many thanks!

Comment: Check answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61642736/how-to-generate-source-code-from-avro-schema-in-maveneclipse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate source code from avro schema in maven(eclipse)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61642736/how-to-generate-source-code-from-avro-schema-in-maveneclipse)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the avro-maven-plugin with the 'induce' goal to covert a Pojo class to a avsc schema file

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>induce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <javaSourceDirectories>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/annotations/src/main/java</javaSourceDirectories>
                        <allowNull>true</allowNull>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```